# Can I "recreate" a sparsebundle?

Tags: macos, google-drive, sparsebundle

I am using Google Drive, and have downloaded the application to my MacBook (I'm running the latest version of Mavericks). I have uploaded an encrypted `.sparsebundle` to Drive (the file itself is over 50GB). In the future if I need to access that file, it seems that I will need to have the Google Drive application installed on the computer from which I want to access that disk image (which will sync entire files to the computer through the application), because Google Drive *online* will only allow you to export 2GB worth of zipped data at a time (when I right click the file in Google Drive online and select "Download", it attempts to ZIP the entire `.sparsebundle`, but then I get an error saying that it can only download the first 2GB worth; obviously, this will corrupt my disk image.)

Is there a way to work around this? My only solution I can think of is to do this in the terminal:

```
touch somefilename.sparsebundle
```

And then tediously select 2GB worth of bands at a time from Drive online, show the package contents of the newly created `.sparsebundle`, and manually drop each 2GB worth of bands into a "bands" folder (which I will create inside the `.sparsebundle`). In other words, I'd basically be trying to recreate the original disk image by piecing it together manually. I'm not quite sure whether this would even be possible though, and I'd like to get some input before I spend several trying to piece together a 50+ GB encrypted disk image, when I'm not sure whether it would work in the first place.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Have you tried using the 
[Google Drive Web APIs](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/manage-downloads) to download the file?

Comment: @ssnobody, interesting, I had not considered that option. I'll look it over and see if that works.